# Difference between NOT false and true

Tags: c

I have this chunk of code:

```
if ( ( data.is_err != FALSE ) && ( available != FALSE ) )
    {
        Set_Dtc_TimerChange(DTC_VPOS, +dt_ms);
    }
```

Why would you use not equal to false instead of just equal to true? Is there a difference at all?

Comment: Several correct answers are already below.  I'd like to add that when I see macros for such basic values, I do not trust them, because I have seen surprising macro values in the past (and wasted far too much time).  So I always look them up when I see them, once, just to be safe.

Comment: If they are from some crappy non-standard compiler, but use `0` for `FALSE`, you should not compare like that at all. The correct - and much easier understandable) way for boolean (or true/false `int`) variables would be to write `if ( data.is_err && available ) ...`. Read out loud, this directly states what you want, instead of having to think thrice what is intended.

Answer (score 12):

This is a C question rather than an EE, but as C is very close to the hardware....

The old C definition of false is 0, with *all other values being true*, that is

```
if( 0 ){ ... }
```

will not execute the ... code, but for instance

```
if( 1 ){ ... }
if( -1 ){ ... }
if( 42 ){ ... }
```

all will. Hence you can test a truth value for being equal to FALSE (which is defined as 0), but when you want to compare it to true, which value would you use for true? Some say TRUE must be defined as (!FALSE), but that would yield -1, which is *a* value of true, but not the only one.

Hence programmers tended to avoid conparing to TRUE.

Modern C should have solved this by defining TRUE to be (I think) 1, but that stil has funny consequences, like

```
int probably( void ){ return 42; }
if( probably() ){ ... }
if( probably() == TRUE ){ ... }
```

Here the blame is on probbaly(), which returns an abiguous truth value.

Personally, I would have written

```
if ( data.is_err && available ) { ... }
```

which I think is much more readable and avoids the comparisons.

(BTW how can something be available when there is a data error?)

Comment: "available" could refer to anything, and the error in the data could be a logical/semantic one, not an inherent data structure/quality issue. So who knows?? Only the OP lol.

Comment: True (for some value of true...) but to my eyes it looks suspicious, and would deserve at least a comment.

Comment: RE: "Modern C should have solved this by defining TRUE to be (I think) 1". Why not just use the solution of other modern languages and have a `bool` type with only two values: `false` and `true`?

Comment: RE: "when you want to compare it to true, which value would you use for true?". You don't have to compare anything to true. You can just use the condition itself (or its negation) as the predicate of the if clause (like you do yourself in your final example).

Comment: @The Photon: because that would break old code, which is a big NO NO for a language that has a large installed code base.

Comment: @The Photon: the question was 'why compare != FALSE instead of == TRUE'. It is true that you don't have to compare (as I say BTW), but that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @ThePhoton `Why not just use the solution of other modern languages and have a bool type with only two values: false and true` They did with C99. It took them a while..

Comment: I'm surprised that a C compiler would consider that `42 != TRUE`, being it the answer to life, the universe and everything...

Comment: "must be defined as `(!FALSE)`, but that would yield `-1`"  No, that's `~FALSE`.  `!FALSE` is (positive) `1`.

Comment: @BenVoigt except when it isn't, of course. `-1` is a good alternative that some implementations have chosen, because it makes `&` and `&&` logically equivalent.

Comment: @hobbs: We are talking about C, right?  A language where `!0` is anything except `1` is not C.

Comment: @BenVoigt apparently my memory is faulty and I was thinking of other languages. Oh well. :)

Comment: Modern C **does** provide `bool`, `true` and `false` since at least 1999. Yet C still defines `0` or a _null pointer_ to evaluate false for logical operators. This for good reasons, not just legacy, like many other modern languages, including C++, Python, etc. Homebrew/vendor-specific crap like `TRUE`, etc. should be burried deep in history and legacy code, but never be used for new code. Note that logical operators always yield `1` for true. This not just since C99.

Comment: @ThePhoton: Did you ever had a look at C99?

Comment: @Ricardo: Wrong question!

Comment: @hobbs, you're thinking of Forth.

Answer (score 8):

This code can be safely replaced by:

```
if (  data.is_err &&  available ) { 
    Set_Dtc_TimerChange(DTC_VPOS, +dt_ms); 
}
```

unless the `FALSE` has some non-traditional definition somewhere in the program. A good compiler will produce equivalent code for either form, but the more readable one is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

C does not have a Boolean type. Instead, it treats 0 as false and any other value as true. As a result, there is no value that you can test against to determine whether a value represents true. That's not important if you write idiomatic C code: `if (x) ...` will always do the right thing. Folks who are uncomfortable with this idiom like to test explicitly against some representation of false, but never explain why they limit that to one level. After all, `x != FALSE` is just a value, and by the same argument needs to be tested: `if ((x != FALSE) != FALSE)...`.

Comment: C99 have introduced a `_Bool` type.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - thanks for the information. My knowledge of C hasn't been updated to match C99.

Comment: @EugeneSh. While that is true and super useful, sometime in embedded systems we get stuck with some, er, less than compliant toolchains or are stuck with C89 due to "legacy" code. Definitely use C99 and true booleans if you are able, but unfortunately this still gets to rear its ugly head sometimes.

Comment: C did have boolean expresions since its start. They were just represented by an `int` value of `0` or `1`. Thats why legacy code often `#define FALSE 0` `#define TRUE !FALSE`

Comment: @Olaf - using that definition of `TRUE` does not have the same semantics as using an expression in an `if` statement. There are many values of `x` for which `if(x) whatever();` will call the function but `if(x==TRUE) whatever();` will not. Code that uses macros like those is unidiomatic and dangerous.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Comparing with `true`/`false` is in general the wrong approach and less clear. You should never do that, but use the first variant in your comment. Sidenote: If `x` is `bool`, the comparison **is** identical.